# "cordova platform check" not working?

Tags: cordova

Running MacOS.

`cordova -v`:

6.5.0

`cordova platform ls`:

Installed platforms:

android 6.1.2

ios 4.3.1

`cordova platform check`:

```
Subproject Path: CordovaLib

ios @ 4.3.1; current did not install, and thus its version cannot be determined


cp: no such file or directory: /var/folders/wm/xyqns5v17zz0jyfhh9bpy_bm0000gp/T/cordova-platform-check-1489628347082/platforms/ios/HelloC
ordova/.gitignore


grep: no such file or directory: /var/folders/wm/xyqns5v17zz0jyfhh9bpy_bm0000gp/T/cordova-platform-check-1489628347082/platforms/ios/Hell
oCordova.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj


sed: no such file or directory: /var/folders/wm/xyqns5v17zz0jyfhh9bpy_bm0000gp/T/cordova-platform-check-1489628347082/platforms/ios/Hello
Cordova.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj


Error: Entry not found in project file for sub-project: CordovaLib/CordovaLib.xcodeproj
```

This output doesn't look right to me. Something wrong with `cordova platform check`?

Comment: `ios 4.3.1` that's awefully old and unsupported. I suggest you start by updating that to 9

Comment: that's the version of cordova-ios, not iOS. https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios

Comment: report it on http://issues.cordova.io. EDIT: I just saw you already did https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12576